# DateTime.Now Issue in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

```
var insertDate = DateTime.Now
```

I opened windows application on `25/07/2013` but submitted on `29/07/2013`.

In the Database, `25/07/2013` is stored instead of `29/07/2013`.

Please suggest me why?

Thanks in advance.

Prasad

Comment: Do you really think you've shown enough code here for us to guess at the answer?

Comment: "Please suggest me why?" Because this code: `var insertDate = DateTime.Now` runs when the application starts, not when the form is submitted?

Comment: Because now yesterday's now is yesterday

Comment: Do not run such code on 42th of each month

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Your need to set your insertDate right before you write the value to the database.

```
insertDate = DateTime.Now;
// write to database
```

Answer (score 1):

The line of code

```
var insertDate = DateTime.Now;
```

doesn't "bind" that value to "the current time" so that it is "always up-to-date" but it sets the value of that variable `insertDate` to the date/time at the instant of execution.

So [like Derek already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925956/121309), set this variable just before you perform the insert.